# when I press Image, image changed to other image

Tags: android, image, button

for instance, i made imageview on XML, and i like to make like this.

when I click that image, image is change to another image.

so I want to make image button, how can i do like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the ImageView satisfy your requirment. You can try this code :

```
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //You can set new image to the imageView by resource id, bitmap, drawable...
            imageView.setImageResource(resId)
        }
    });
```